# Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] Laravel 5.6

Tags: redis, laravel-5.6

I've been struggling with starting redis on my system and all i get is **connection refused** ! 
I tried :  config/database , switch between 127.0.0.1 and localhost and ....
So what can i do to make it work ?
 Notice : i'm using laradock and other packages are working just fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using localhost or 127.0.0.1, you must use the ((redis)) in .env Laravel.

According to the above code:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: What if one want to use elasticache?

Comment: It works. Why does the 127.0.0.1 not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install redis-server
```

Then open this file with text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

find supervised and set to systemd:

```
supervised systemd

sudo systemctl restart redis.service
```